# Visual MFC - Access edit control from another class

Tags: c++, mfc

I have 2 classes in MFC, Class1 is Dialog Class with 1 edit text and 1 button. I added Class 2 (right click on project, select add->Class, I'm not sure about base class, so it's default "CWnd")

In class 2, I implemented a function "input" to change value in edit text from Class 1

```
void Class2::Input()
{
   UpdateData(true);
   Class1 cl;
   cl.edit1 = 10; //edit1 is the variable name of edit text
   UpdateData(false);

}
```

and when button in Class1 clicked, it call Class2::Input

but when I clicked button, bug appear "debug assertion failed" (failed at UpdateData function)

please help me access edit text in Class1 from Class2
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your function creates a new Class1, so it is not the same object as the Class1 that calls Input. Furthermore, the new Class1 is a CWnd that has not had its window created, so any call like UpdateData to its members will assert because the window and its controls do not exist.

What you need is for Class1 to pass 'this' to Class2. You could do that with a parameter to the Input function, or you could pass it as a parameter to the Class2 constructor.